# angular 4 ngIf alternative

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I have a drop-down menu that you could choose the currency and based on the chosen currency, but right now I'm using `ngif` to show the currency but and it works fine with only two currencies but for more currencies I have to add more ngif and to me that's not logical since the HTML code for that page is going to be huge ( 100 different currencies = 100 ngif's)

this is what I have now:

Company.ts

```
   currencyItems: string[] =  ['MXN', 'PHP'];
   currency: string = this.currencyItems[0];
```

company.html

```
<div class="col-md-5" *ngIf = "currency = 'MXN'">
      <input type="number" name="mxn" id="mxn" [(ngModel)]="newCompany.currency.mxn" class="form-control">
</div>


<div class="col-md-5" *ngIf = "currency = 'PHP'">
      <input type="number" name="php" id="php" [(ngModel)]="newCompany.currency.php" class="form-control">
</div>
```

what i want to achieve is, is there any way that I only have one block of code 
something like that

```
<div class="col-md-5">
      <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="newCompany.currency.<changes base on drop-down selection>" class="form-control">
</div>
```

and also

```
<td>{{company.currency.mxn}}</td>
```

to

```
<td>{{company.currency.<changes base on drop-down selection>}}</td>
```

I know I can use ngSwitch, but that's still is going to be lots of code too.

Answer (score 1):

Use a separate property altogether. For example `selectedCurrency`. Then when a new option is selected from the dropdown, assign it to `selectedCurrency`

```
<div class="col-md-5">
    <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="selectedCurrency" class="form-control">
</div>

<td>{{selectedCurrency}}</td>
```

Comment: 'company.currency.mxn' is a rate that I'm getting it from an API,  ex. company.currency.mxn = 19.12.   company.currency.php = 24.55 .  so when I choose  MXN from drop-down menu I want to see mxn value and vice-versa

Comment: @Milad The logic should still be the same. User chooses `mxn` from dropdown -> make api call to get value -> assign value to `selectedCurrency` for display

Comment: does this logic work if I have about 100 different companies? so all the companies are listed in a rows, and each one has different currency rate, so by selecting mxn from drop done menu I want show all the currency rates that I'm getting from API to be mxn, visa an versa for other currency rate.

Comment: @Milad In that case, each company should have its own `selectedCurrency` property. For example, I assume you are using ngFor to show the 100 companies. Your data may look something like `companies = [{name: 'A', selectedCurrency: 0.7}, {name: 'B', selectedCurrency: 1}, ...];`. Now when a user chooses `mxn`, you would loop through your data and change the `selectedCurrency` value for each company

Comment: LLai @LLai, Thank you I'll try it now